# Email Sending Failed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am developing an application for sending emails. I have used the `EDMESSAGE` framework. I developed the application in `MAC OS X 10.6.7` and i got it working. When i installed the application in `MAC OS X 10.7.2`, email sending is failed.

The error that i am getting is:

> Host (null) (() ())has no IPV4 address

Can anybody help me with a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the EDMESSAGE forum there is this [EDMessage on 10.7 Lion / IPv6](http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=236&sid=96a5e365ee9084f7ca78a162350c6070)

Basicly it looks like EDMESSAGE does not support connection via IPV6 which is what your 10.7 Mac may be trying to do.

By the way that info was not hard to find, about 30 seconds of using google.  Even with this being the first time hearing about EDMESSAGE.  ;-)

Comment: oh just 30 seconds! ok next time will try to make it in 25 seconds. thanks :-)